# iOS: rotating a view, gradient layer of button does not autoresizing

Tags: ios, uibutton, gradient, autoresizingmask

I have a UIButton called `nextbutton` in a View. I already set `autoresizing` this button in the `Interface Builder`. In the `viewDidLoad` , I call this method to set gradient for this button. The `gradientLayer` nicely fits to `nextbutton` in the Portrait mode of the app, however, it does not in the landscape mode. Any suggestion for this? thanks a lot.

```
-(void)toSetGradientNextButtons{
    CAGradientLayer* gradientLayer = [[CAGradientLayer alloc] init];
    [gradientLayer setBounds:[nextbutton bounds]];
    [gradientLayer setPosition:CGPointMake([nextbutton bounds].size.width/2,[nextbutton bounds].size.height/2)];

    [gradientLayer setColors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor],(id)[[UIColor cyanColor] CGColor], nil]];
    [[nextbutton layer] insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
    [gradientLayer release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'was just solving exactly the same issue. Following method is called on viewWillAppear and viewDidLayoutSubviews in my code.

First, I'm doing a check to see if the button already has this layer (from previous UI state and/or rotation). If it does, custom layer is removed.
Then it inserts the gradient layer while tagging it with custom name, that allows to easily find it in the first place.

```
- (void)setupGradientOnLayoutSubviews
{
    // First, we'll remove old custom gradient layer if present (e.g. on rotation)
    for (__strong CALayer *layer in [[[self button] layer] sublayers]) {
        if ([[layer name] isEqualToString: @"myCustomGradient"] == YES) {
            [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
            break;
        }
    }

    // Configure the gradient
    _gradientLayer = [[CAGradientLayer alloc] init];
    _gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.button.frame.size.width, self.button.frame.size.height);
    _gradientLayer.masksToBounds = NO;
    _gradientLayer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    _gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[RGB(205, 6, 106) CGColor], (id)[RGB(147, 2, 76) CGColor], nil];
    _gradientLayer.borderColor = [RGB(193, 5, 99) CGColor];
    _gradientLayer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

    _gradientLayer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    _gradientLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1,1);
    _gradientLayer.shadowRadius = 2;
    _gradientLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.2;
    _gradientLayer.name = @"myCustomGradient";

    // Add the gradient layer
    [self.button.layer insertSublayer:_gradientLayer atIndex:0];
}
```